# Basic Question about AWS Security Groups - When do use Inbound vs Outbound?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I had a very specific question regarding SGs speficcally around Inbound and Outbound rules.

*Situation*
Lets say we have an EC2 instance with `SG-12345` which is trying to talk to a MYSQL database on `SG-98765` and I want an Ec2 to talk to the database.
I read the AWS documentation that Security Groups are stateful. Given this the question I had was:-

Is there any difference between
adding the DATABASE SG (`SG-98765`) to the OUTBOUND RULES of the EC2 (`SG-12345`)
vs
adding the EC2 SG (`SG-12345`) to the INBOUND RULES of the DATABASE SB (`SG-98765`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between adding the DATABASE SG (SG-98765) to
> the OUTBOUND RULES of the EC2 (SG-12345) vs adding the EC2 SG
> (SG-12345) to the INBOUND RULES of the DATABASE SB (SG-98765)?

Yes. If you don't add both rules, the connection will be denied.

The statefulness of security groups does not apply across multiple security groups. It simply allows responses to requests that were permitted by the security group to also be permitted by the security group. Both security groups still have to allow the initial network request.

Often you will see security groups on an EC2 instance allow all outbound traffic by default, or allow all outbound traffic to the VPC CIDR perhaps. And then the inbound rules on the database would control what can actually connect to the database.

Comment: thank you ...where is this in the official docment? I was trawling through it but wasnt able to specifically find this

Comment: What specifically are you looking for in the official documentation? If you are looking for something that says statefullness doesn't apply across multiple security groups you won't find that, because that was just an incorrect assumption you made.

Comment: i see.. its parallax. i read in one of the tutorials that said "If you add a rule to outbound" then that inbound rule on the target app does not need to add the rule since stateful think it was just a bad article